# Push Notification, alert message not receiving on iPhone

Tags: asp.net, push-notification

I am working on Push notifications for iPhone. I am sending notification on button click, but the iPhone developer is not receiving the alert message. Can anyone plz help me?
This is my method --

```
protected void btnPush_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string devicetoken = "bhsdse78 d52c6a34 273de5f7 27947945 24736e36 33d93a6c 3147a416 434995eb";
    try
    {
        if (devicetoken != "")
        {
            //lblError.Visible = false;
            string p12FileName = "D:/Worksapace/Coupzila/Certificates(3).p12"; // change this to reflect your own certificate
            string p12Password = "seas"; // change this
            bool sandBox = true;
            int numConnections = 1; // you can change the number of connections here
            var notificationService = new NotificationService(sandBox, p12FileName, p12Password, numConnections);
            var deviceToken = devicetoken; // put in your device token here
            var notification = new Notification(deviceToken);

            notification.Payload.Alert.Body = "Hi this is push notification test message.";
            notification.Payload.Sound = "default";
            notification.Payload.Badge = 1;
            notification.Payload.HideActionButton = true;
            if (notificationService.QueueNotification(notification))
            { }
            else
            { }
            // This ensures any queued notifications get sent befor the connections are closed
            notificationService.Close();
            notificationService.Dispose();

        }
        else
        {
           //lblError.Visible = true;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

This method is running successfully, but not getting notifications on iPhone, Whtz problem in my code?
Help me out, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First, Remove the empty characters from your deviceToken.

Second, Put @ sign for your fileName;

string p12FileName = @"D:/Worksapace/Coupzila/Certificates(3).p12";

And for the last step implement your catch, like;

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is an error from push notification. Details:\n" + ex);
    }
```

And good with Apple.